# renaming and replacing the contents of a string in java

Tags: java, string

> String fileOne = "C:/1236.pdf";
>
> String fileTwo = "C:/22.pdf";
>
> String mergedFileLocation = "C:/myMergedData.pdf";

after the merging is done

**rename an existing file**

i need to rename and replacing  the mergedFileLocation equals to fileOne

i.e., **myMergedData.pdf to 1236.pdf**

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear whether you're asking about changing the value of the variable, or about actually renaming the file.

If it's the former, then simply use variable assignment: `mergedFileLocation = fileOne`.

If it's the latter, the method you're looking for is [`File.renameTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

```
if (new File(mergedFileLocation).renameTo(new File(fileOne))) {
  // rename successful
} else {
  // rename has failed
}
```

Comment: nope bro.... how to replace the contents nor replace tat string

Comment: i tried this method but its giving false

Comment: @user813995, then it's most likely one of two possibilities: 1) you (or the user executing the Java app) has insufficient rights to create a new file in `fileOne`, or 2) the file at location `mergedFileLocation` is being held/opened by some other process.